# I got this error (#132000) Number of parameters does not match the expected number of params

Tags: postman

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIzAv.png)
Here this is my custom template which I have created. Using this template am
trying to send what's app msg but i got 132000 error

```
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
     "recipient_type": "individual",
    "to": "917760569250",
    "type": "template",
    "template": {
        "name": "media_messages",
        "language": {
            "code": "en_US"
        },
        "components": [
          {
            "type":"header",
            "parameters":[
              {
                "type":"document",
                "document":{
                    "id": "1195808994372455"
}
            }
      ]
    },
       {
        "type": "body",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "Document"
          }
]
    }
      ]
}  
}
```